# Idempotent non-associative algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

This is inspired by [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82365/is-every-finitely-generated-idempotent-ring-singly-generated-as-a-two-sided-ideal)  question by Andreas Thom.

Let $L$ be a finitely generated Lie ring (or Lie algebra over a field) such that $L=[L,L]$, that is the Abelianization of $L$ is 0. Is it true that $L$ is generated as an ideal by one element?

If the answer is "no", can we consider the universal enveloping algebra of the counterexample to get a counterexample to the question about associative rings?

Same question can be asked for Jordan rings and other classical non-associative rings.

**Update**  Consider the same question for arbitrary (non-associative) rings. That case should be easier.

Comment: We thought about Lie algebras too, but could not see any chance to control the number of generators as a 2-sided ideal.

Comment: How about general non-associative algebras? 

Comment: I do not know. I have no experience with general non-associative algebras. It is already hard to construct idempotent examples; the free non-associative ring on $n$ idempotents does not look idempotent.

Comment: @Andreas: An "idempotent" ring is a ring $R$ with the property that $R*R$ generates $R$ as an Abelian group (i.e. every element is a sum of products). Certainly the free idempotent generated ring is "idempotent".  I do not see how it can be generated as an ideal by one element. 